# Как отследить клик по любой ссылке на странице?

Tags: javascript

Суть в том, что хочу затемнять страницу, после нажатия на ссылку. Т.е., в тот момент, пока браузер не загрузил ещё новую страницу.

Мне необходимо отследить клик по любой ссылке на странице и выполнить функцию. Не подскажите, как мне отследить нажатие на ссылку?

*Нужно именно на чистом JS.*

Comment: жаль, что нельзя на jQuery. Там одна строка $('a').on('click',function(){ });

Comment: @DenisI, эта запись эквивалента `document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', ev => {}, {})` на нативном js

Comment: @Voprositel = `document.anchors` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для всей страницы лучше делать через [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), определить функцию клика, далее убедится что клик произошел именно на ссылке. Для того чтобы ссылка не открылась (действие по умолчанию) это нужно запретить методом `preventDefault()`

```
 <a href="https://google.com">открыть гугл</a>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('click', filter, false)
  function filter(e){
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A'){ // провека что кликнули на ссылку
      console.log(e.target.href);  // получаем URL адрес ссылки
      e.preventDefault();          // отменяем переход 
         
      /*  реализуете свою логику  */

      window.location.href = e.target.href; // переходите по ссылке
    }
  }
 </script>
```

для более надежного перехвата нужно не забыть про события:

- onmouseup
- oncontextmenu
- onkeydown
- touchstart

если на окно больше никаких событий не будете навешивать можно сделать
это цепочкой присвоений:

```
window.onclick = window.onmouseup = window.oncontextmenu =
window.onkeydown = window.touchstart = function(e){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    e.preventDefault(); // Отменяем переход по ссылке
    console.info(e.target.href);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Ссылка</a>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://yandex.ru">Глубоко</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```